# Mobile browsers don't fire up resize event when hiding address bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, mobile

I have two sections on my website, whose height I set to `window.innerHeight`. When the resize event is fired the height is updated.

This works perfectly on my desktop, but on my android phone I get some problems.

In Chrome for android, if you scroll down so that the address bar gets hidden and the window size changes, Chrome fires a resize event and the height is updated.

Firefox and the default android browser don't fire this resize event after hiding the address bar. If I change the orientation of the device manually from portrait to landscape and back the height is updated like it should.

So I tried to dispatch an orientationchange event myself, but this didn't work.

Is there a way I can get Firefox and the default browser to behave like Chrome?

Here is the [website](http://db.tt/j0iTbjtk).

Comment: Since you can't change the default browser behavior, you may have to check to see if the height has changed ever 5 seconds or so.

Comment: I tried this, but the problem is that the value of `window.innerHeight` is not updated.

Comment: Are you sure the window height changes? Mobile browsers can be funny about these things.

Comment: In Firefox the window height only changes after an orientation change. If I just scroll down the window height doesn't change.

Comment: I have also the same problem, when i scroll down in Google Chrome Android toolbar is hiding and that changes the value of height. When i scroll up the toolbar will show and again it changes the value of the height.

Answer (score 8):

Indeed mobile browsers (tested Android/Chrome iOs/Safari), when toggling address bar, fire the `resize` event only after user takes finger off the screen.

However we can use the `touchmove` event, that made the browser hide or show the address bar in the first place. In the handler we can use `window.innerHeight` property to detect changes in the viewport height. Using jQuery:

```
$(window).on('resize touchmove', function () {
    // adjust heights basing on window.innerHeight
    // $(window).height() will not return correct value before resizing is done
});
```

It's not perfect, but nevertheless it is the only working solution I came up with.

The whole behavior is kinda quirky, because even elements styled using `position: fixed` will be redrawn only after the touch ends.

Additionally if the adjustment function causes lag, the handler should probably be debounced.