# Android and IOS mobile devices :calculate browser screen height excluding address bar and navigation bar height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to calculate browser height without considering browser address bar and bottom navigation bar height.

The value of `screen.height` will give the full browser height. I've highlighted area in orange in attached image. Looking for generic solution which will work on all mobile devices

[image: attache image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Android Chrome Browser Address bar height in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50990006/get-android-chrome-browser-address-bar-height-in-js)

Answer (score 5):

Easily:

```
window.innerHeight
```

There is an [algorithm](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=189112#c7) to obtain the height of the viewport excluding, if rendered, the horizontal scrollbar.

See also the [offical docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerHeight).