# How to calculate size of browser's address bar

Tags: javascript

I want to resize my window browser to the content size and I am using `window.resizeTo` function [(ref)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resizeTo) to do this. However I cannot calculate height of browser's address bar. I've tried

`window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight`

but it also includes the height of browser interface. Is there any way to get the size of address bar in browsers. Take a look at the following picture; I want size of red area or maybe a way to hide it and remove it from the outerHeight calculation

[image: Size of address bar]

Comment: Why don't you just use ``innerHeight``?

Comment: The size of your innerHeight and innerWidth are the exact dimensions of your viewport, no need of other properties or calculations

Comment: I don't want to get the size of window. I want to set a custom size to it with `window.resizeTo` function. If I set e.g. 500*500, the inner width and height are less than 500. [window.resizeTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resizeTo)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50990006/get-android-chrome-browser-address-bar-height-in-js

Comment: @Pete Thanks. I saw it before but I couldn't find my answer there :(

Comment: It would help if you explain what you are trying to do - what you need the height for as this may be an xy problem

Comment: Let's make it simple. Assume that the body size is 500x500. I want to set the size of my window to 500x500. I tried to use `window.resizeTo` function but it doesn't work. It set the size of whole browser window ( including scroll bars, title bars, etc ) to 500x500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not doable with javascript. You can do a system-dependent hack on your own system, but the moment the browser or system changes, this will be thrown off, because all systems have their own chrome (window decoration) and they are all different.

Comment: I think you are right. I should consider a fixed padding instead of exact size :(