# How to identify Address bar in Mobile Device?

Tags: javascript, mobile, responsive

When you scroll down or up in any web site the Address bar show/hide. I wish identify when the bar is hidden or visible.

**Example:**

```
if (chromeBarIsHidden()) {
console.log('a');
} else {
console.log('b');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## There is no exact solution

There is no native way to do this in any browser. However, using the dimensions and window resize events, there have been solutions developed. [See this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51176654/12359228). However, unless absolutely necessary, I would not recommend this for the following reasons:

- The browser may be on a computer with a window resize, causing the `window.onresize` event to not accurately represent the change
- Different mobile browsers handle the hiding of the top bar differently. The above solution could work if you are sure that the client is on Android Google Chrome.
- Users may expect UI elements in your webpage to move with the top app bar being hidden, causing an inconsistent user experience across webpages

---

### Alternatives

#### `window.onresize` Event

The `window.onresize` event will fire whenever the browser's window size changes. This can be used to resize and change the layout of the page through JavaScript with different window sizes. To use this, see the example below.

```
window.onresize = function() {
    // Do something on resize
}
```

#### `window.innerHeight` Property

The `window.innerHeight` property returns the view height of the viewport. This can be used to determine if layout arrangements will need to change based on height.

```
var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
```

---

### Responsive design

A better alternative to changing things depending on the viewport size, which changes when the address bar hides itself. See [this article by w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp).